# Why doesn't changing the bound property update the checkbox's visual state during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application with a drop down and a checkbox:

[image]

The XAML looks like the following:

```xml
<StackPanel>
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   <CheckBox Content="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I would like to force the checkbox to go unchecked when I select "Word" from the drop down. I've tried to achieve this by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my data context and then subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event of the property which represents the selected item from the drop down, `SelectedFileType`. Here's the code I have so far:

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string m_selectedFileType;
   public List<string> FileTypes { get; set; }
   public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

   public string SelectedFileType
   {
      get => m_selectedFileType;
      set
      {
         m_selectedFileType = value;
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs((nameof(SelectedFileType))));
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public MainViewModel()
   {

      FileTypes = new List<string>();
      FileTypes.Add("Excel");
      FileTypes.Add("Word");

      PropertyChanged += FileTypeChanged;
      SelectedFileType = "Excel";

      IsChecked = true;
   }

   private void FileTypeChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (SelectedFileType == "Word")
      {
         IsChecked = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the app and switch from "Excel" to "Word" in the drop down, the check box remains unchanged, so I feel that I am missing something.

I have already tried switching to `TwoWay` binding and using `UpdateSourceTrigger` but none of those things have worked.

Why does modifying the `SelectedFileType` property during runtime not affect the visual state of the checkbox, even though I have clearly set it as a two-way binding in XAML?

## EDIT

The relevant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0#direction-of-the-data-flow) does mention the following:

> To detect source changes (applicable to OneWay and TwoWay bindings), the source must implement a suitable property change notification mechanism such as INotifyPropertyChanged.

I'm starting to think that perhaps `TwoWay` binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged` sort of go hand in hand...

Comment: You have to set `IsChecked` property in similair way as you set `SelectedFileType` - i.e. you also need to raise `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn `IsChecked` is already two-way bound. Why would I need to raise an event in its setter? I was under the impression that two-way binding ought to take care of that...

Comment: @user32882 Is won't take care of it. You should raise a property changed event on the checkbox as well. Also, seems kind of pointless to raise an event for `FileTypeChanged` when you have a binding to `SelectedFileType`

Comment: Well, the event is how you let UI know that something has changed.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn `TwoWay` is also supposed to let the UI know that something has changed, so why doesn't it work here?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn In the way he created it, yes. But practically he does not need it. The event is supposed to fire when the combo box selected item is changed, which is also when the `SelectedFileType` setter is triggered thus he can just place the code from the event inside the setter. Of course making sure that the code does not interfere with the setter behavior.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I just noticed how wrong the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IsChecked`property doesn't raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

Whenever you want to send data from the source property (e.g. `IsChecked`) to a target property (e.g. `CheckBox.IsChecked`), you must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`. Otherwise the `Binding` won't know that it has to update the target.

`BindingMode.TwoWay` only means that data can be send back to the source. This mode also includes `BindingMode.OneWay` behavior to make it two way. In other words, when the the binding target (e.g. `CheckBox`) changes the value of a two way binding the target has to raise a change notification (via dependency property) to notify the `Binding` that it has to update the binding source.
Still the source has to raise a change notification in case it updates the value to trigger the `Binding` (it's actually the `BindingExpression` to be more precise).

The binding is passive in that it doesn't actively send data between source and target. The sender (binding source in `OneWay` and binding source and binding target in `TwoWay` or binding target in `OneWyToSource mode) must always explicitly trigger the binding to transfer data by raising a change notification (by implementing` INotifyPropertyChanged`and raise`PropertyChanged` or by implementing the property as dependency property).

See [Microsoft Docs: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Furthermore, your current code will update the `IsChecked` property every time that any property changes. You  must filter for the correct property in your `PropertyChanegd` event handler:

```cs
private void FileTypeChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.PropertyName)
  {
    case nameof(this.IsChecked):
      if (this.SelectedFileType == "Word")
      {
        this.IsChecked = false;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

But because you are the the owner of those properties, you don't have to handle the `PropertyChanged` event. Instead invoke a e.g. `OnIsChekedChanged` method from the property setter.
You can find a better and recommended `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation in the .NET docs: [`PropertyChanged` example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-7.0#examples).

The improved and fixed version of your code could look as follows:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyProeprtyChanged
{
  private bool isChecked;
  public bool IsChecked
  {
    get => this.isChecked;
    set
    {
      this.isChecked = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnIsCheckedChanged();
    }
  }

  private string selectedFileType;
  public string SelectedFileType
  {
    get => this.selectedFileType;
    set
    {
      bool oldValue = this.IsChecked;
      this.selectedFileType = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnIsCheckedChanged(oldValue, value);
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnIsCheckedChanged(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
  {
    if (this.SelectedFileType.Equals("Word", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
      this.IsChecked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to notify the view that the `IsChecked` property has changed.

I took the freedom to modify your code a bit, this should work:

This would be the XAML

```
<StackPanel>
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileType}"/>
   <CheckBox Content="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and this is where the change will happen:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectedFileType = "Excel";
        IsChecked = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // Implement a method to raise property changed calls
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Created a new private field and exposed it using a property for code consistency
    // Also used ObservableCollection because it notifies the view when an item is added to the collection
    private ObservableCollection<string> file_types = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Word", "Excel" };
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileTypes
    {
        get => file_types;
        private set => file_types = value; // You usually don't need to recreate an ObservableCollection, only modify it
    }

    private bool is_checked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => is_checked;
        set
        {
            is_checked = value;
            // Notifiy the view of the change
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
        }
    }

    private string m_selectedFileType;
    public string SelectedFileType
    {
        get => m_selectedFileType;
        set
        {
            m_selectedFileType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFileType));

            // Use the existing binding to the property instead of an event
            if (SelectedFileType == "Word")
            {
                // this will trigger the property setter thus triggering the OnPropertyChanged method
                IsChecked = false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I think you have misunderstood how `Binding Mode` actually works. I found [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/two-way-binding-in-wpf/) to be pretty easy to understand.

TLDR;
Adding any `Mode` to a binding requires that the elements have a common binding property. For example a `Slider` and a `TextBox`. The `Slider` has its value bound to a property called `SliderValue`(example) and the `TextBox` has its `Text` property bound to the same `SliderValue` property. The `Binding Mode` just gives us control over which of these control can change the view value of the other. Notice that they both have a common property they are bound to, which in your case is not true.

Considering this code as our context:

```
<Slider Name="Slider1" Value="0" SmallChange="1" Maximum="100" ></Slider>

<TextBox Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Slider1,Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

`OneWay` - this will allow the slider to change the value of the text box but not the other way around
`OneWayToSource` - this will allow the text box to change the value of the slider but not the other way around
`Two way` - this will allow both components to update each other

Your implementation of a `Binding Mode` follows none of this.

Comment: So what's the point of `TwoWay` in this scenario?

Comment: None, just forgot to remove it. My bad :)

Comment: I mean in general. If `TwoWay` can't update `IsChecked` as soon as its bound property is changed, then what's the point of having `TwoWay` in the first place?

Comment: Take a look at the article and explanation I added in the last edit.

Comment: I don't think that article explains it well, I will look for information elsewhere.

Comment: you can also bind to regular .NET properties, not sure where you got the idea that binding is only for UI elements.

Comment: I never said it was only for UI Elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254147/discussion-between-darko6977-and-user32882).